# Selectable TreeView File Browser MVVM, cant display tree

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

Hit a wall, Im new to the MVVM structure and need help displaying my tree. I need to display a file browser like tree. After I moved to mvvm my tree stopped displaying. I have made a model with methods inside it to build a file tree. Here is my model below.

```
public class UpdateContents 
{
    public string visibleName { get; set; }
    public string fullPath { get; set; }
    public bool isParent { get; private set; }
    public bool? _isSelected { get; set; }
    public UpdateContents _parent;
    public List<UpdateContents> children { get; private set; }
    public bool? isInitiallySelected { get; set; }

    public UpdateContents(string path, bool parent)
    {
        fullPath = path;
        visibleName = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
        isParent = parent;
        this.children = new List<UpdateContents>();
    }
    public void Initialize()
    {
        foreach (UpdateContents child in this.children)
        {
            child._parent = this;
            child.Initialize();
        }
    }
    public UpdateContents CreateDirectory(string directory)
    {
        UpdateContents groot = new UpdateContents(directory, true);
        groot.isInitiallySelected = true;
        CreateFiles(directory, groot);

        foreach (string dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(directory))
        {
            UpdateContents babygroot = new UpdateContents(dir, true);

            CreateFiles(dir, babygroot);
            CreateFolders(dir, babygroot);
            groot.children.Add(babygroot);
        }
        groot.Initialize();
        return groot;
    }

    private void CreateFiles(string path, UpdateContents parent)
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path))
        {
            UpdateContents files = new UpdateContents(file, false);

            parent.children.Add(files);
        }
        parent.Initialize();
    }
    private void CreateFolders(string path, UpdateContents Parent)
    {
        foreach (string folder in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path))
        {
            UpdateContents folders = new UpdateContents(folder, true);
            CreateFiles(folder, folders);
            CreateFolders(folder, folders);
            Parent.children.Add(folders);
        }
        Parent.Initialize();
    }

}
```

I have a view model, but honestly it doesnt do anything. Ive edited it since changing to mvvm. Below is the view model.

```
    public class MainWindowVM 
{
    public string rootfile { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string _name { get; set; }
    public string _path { get; set; }

    public RelayCommand onBrowse { get; set; }

    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        onBrowse = new RelayCommand(onBrowseCommand);
    }

    public void onBrowseCommand ( object commandInvoker )
    {

        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog win = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

        Nullable<bool> result = win.ShowDialog();

        if (result == true)
        {
            string filename = win.FileName;
            rootfile= filename;

            rootfile = filename;
            int index = rootfile.Length;

            index = index - 4;
            rootfile = rootfile.Remove(index);

            //Get file version for text box
            var fversion = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(filename);
            version = fversion.FileVersion;

            //get date created 
            DateTime fdate = File.GetCreationTime(filename);
            date = fdate.ToString();

            //Display Folder Contents
            showzip(filename);

            UpdateContents test = new UpdateContents(rootfile, true);

            UpdateContents directory = test.CreateDirectory(rootfile);          
        }
    }
```

IN my XAML code i only have the TreeViewObject. Below is the snapshot of the xaml. I know i need to add Hierarchialdata to the xaml But being a novice with mvvm i have no idea how to use it.

```
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Grid.Row="4">
        <TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="5,0,5,5" x:Name="foldersItem" ItemsSource="{Binding foldersItem}" >

        </TreeView>
    </DockPanel>
```

I just need to be sent in the right direction, It seems like my model is building the correct tree structure, but I have no clue how to display it with mvvm!! The code will only unzip folders for now.

Comment: Good article [mvvm](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/simple-mvvm-pattern-in-wpf/). The most important part -  `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Also, your binding is wrong now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to get the `TreeView` to automatically render your items all the way down to the bottom leaf-nodes of your tree.

Here's an article from MSDN explaing all about `TreeView` controls and `HierarchicalDataTemplate` objects : [How to: Use a TreeView to Display Hierarchical Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759035%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Also for MVVM and binding you need to understand the INotifyPropertyChanged interface intimately : [System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Hint:** Any property that is bound to in a VM should raise `PropertyChanged` event in its setter. Also any actions should be implemented through `Command` objects (`System.Input.ICommand` implementations), not event handlers.

Check out Kent Boogart's excellent tutorials on MVVM from base principles: [Kent Boogaart's blog - View Models: POCOs versus DependencyObjects](http://kentb.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/view-models-pocos-versus.html)